# JBoss 7.1.1 Startup error [JBAS015875] missing startup stats

Tags: jboss7.x, startup

When we deploy the service on JBoss and start the JBoss, we expect the successful startup message at the end of the service startup. But, in my case, I'm getting below error. I'm using JBoss 7.1.1

ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: **%s** started (with errors) in **%dms** - Started **%d of %d** services (**%d** services failed or missing dependencies, **%d** services are passive or on-demand)

Has anyone come across this scenario before? My question is, why startup stats are not replacing place holders ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something seems odd as that should be an INFO message. What kind of service are you deploying?

Comment: Its a Restful service. Though, I'm not able to reproduce it on all cases.

Comment: This message should only show up when the server starts. That fact that it's an ERROR instead of INFO is suspicious to me. Is there anything before this message?

Comment: Nothing suspicious except this message. That worries me.Yeah, you are right. It should be a startup successful message.

Comment: Can you try WildFly (http://wildfly.org/downloads/)? I vaguely recall some kind of issue with messages not being formatted properly. This was 2+ years ago so it's been a while :)

Comment: As far as I know it's an ERROR when there are reported errors, and an INFO when everything went well. As seen above you have the "(with errors)".